# what's the __name__ when we import more than one modules in a python script

Tags: python, python-module

When we run a `foo.py` script, the global variable `__name__` is set to `"__main__"`, while when running the following script

```
    #Here we import the foo.py module
    import foo

    print("This is a Stackoverflow question")
```

`__name__` equals `foo`. My question is, if we have another module that we import say `foo1.py`

```
    #Here we import foo.py and foo1.py modules
    import foo, foo1

    print("This is still the same Stackoverflow question")
```

then what is the value of `__name__` in that case? Obviously the above generalises to any number of modules.

P.S.
Before I post the question I tried it myself, and the answer was `__main_`, which confuses more.

Answer (score 1):

`__name__` is always the name of the module. `"__main__"` is just used when the file is *not* used to create a module, i.e., when it is run as a script.

In your first example, `__name__` is only equal to `foo` in `foo.py`, not in the file importing `foo`.

Consider a simple file `tmp.py` containing only

```
print(__name__)
```

If you run this file as a script, the output is `__main__`.

```
$ python tmp.py
__main__
```

If you import it as a module, the output is `tmp`.

```
$ python -c 'import tmp'
tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the imported module is not effected by other imports done in the same script.

```
import foo, foo1

print(f"foo name = {foo.__name__}")
print(f"foo1 name = {foo1.__name__}")
print(f"this scripts name = {__name__}")
```

Result:

```
foo name = foo
foo1 name = foo1
this scripts name = __main__
```

Comment: so for the second script the `__name__` is again `"__main__"` right?

Comment: What do you mean by the second script?

Comment: the script with the two imported modules.

Comment: The name of the script that is run directly (not as a module) is always `__main__`

Comment: Yes. Importing modules does not change the fact that this particular script is being run directly